# Get parameters from wikipedia template

Tags: php, regex

OK, so basically I'm trying to parse a rather simple Wikipedia template.

Let's say we have :

`{{ unbulleted list | item 1 | item 2 | li_style=font-size:88%; }}`

(**hint:** spacing *can* be quite flexible, e.g. `unbulleted list|...` is also possible)

So, you can see that after `unbulleted list`, we have several instances of `| something`.

What I want to match is all of those instance that **do not** contain `=`.

How can this be achieved?

---

This is my current regex (but it's not working...) : http://regexr.com?384sk

```
{{unbulleted list(.+?)?(\|[^=]+)+
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Well, I think I'm rather close to solving the... riddle...

```
\|([^=\|}\r]+)(?=[\|}])
```

http://regexr.com?384sq

Comment: @I19 I need an array with all matches. E.g. `array ( "item 1", "item 2")`. Language is PHP.

Comment: You know that Mediawiki templates are not simple to parse (they're not a regular language), and that there are proper (full-blown) parsers (and even APIs) in PHP available?

Comment: @Bergi Well, I know and I've already studied their code as well. I could write a parser myself. However, my current experiment involves testing a Scraping framework of mine, and an actually small-scale test around `infobox`es. So, a 'complete' solution won't be needed.

Comment: Is regex needed for performance?  If performance is not an issue, couldn't you do a string check for "="?

Comment: @JoshAustin As I've mentioned above, I'm testing my own PHP scraping framework (http://sourceforge.net/projects/scraphp/ - this is an older version though). So, using `RegEx`s (or `XPath`s) is a must for pattern matching.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon.  Whoops!  Sorry.  My brain is apparently not working  right now.  :-P

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: why do you say that you're "close"? How is your solution not okay?

Comment: Hmmmm tougher than I thought ... [Here you go](http://regex101.com/r/bO2tF4)

Answer (score 2):

What about this regex ?

```
(?<=\|)\s*([^|={}]+)\s*(?=\||}})
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/mO0cG4